# Ethereum keystrore file is not created

Tags: uwp, ethereum, go-ethereum

Keystore file is not created when I am creating a new Ethereum wallet account using nethereum and UWP. Also the newly created account is not in the private net.

The new account is created using the following code:

```
var privateKey = txtPassword.Text.ToHexUTF8();
var account = new Nethereum.Accounts.Account(privateKey);
```